# Flutter scroll end when list loads

Tags: flutter, dart

On click I am using this function to scroll down to end of list

```
  void _scrollDown() {
    _controller.animateTo(
      _controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 10),
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    );
  }
```

I have list like this

```
 Widget getBody() {
    final globalProviderState =
        Provider.of<globalProvider>(context, listen: false);

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection(ROOM_COLLECTION)
            .doc(widget.chatroomId)
            .collection('messages')
            .orderBy("date", descending: false)
            // .where(globalProviderState.getID)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return new Text("Loading");
          }

          return Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              controller: _controller,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              padding:
                  EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, left: 20, top: 20, bottom: 80),
              children: List.generate(snapshot.data!.docs.length, (index) {
                int sendId = 1;

                if (index != 0) {
                  if (index + 1 == snapshot.data!.docs.length) {
                    sendId = 3;
                  }
                  if (index + 1 < snapshot.data!.docs.length) {
                    if (snapshot.data!.docs[index]['senderId'] ==
                        snapshot.data!.docs[index + 1]['senderId']) {
                      sendId = 2;
                    }
                    if (snapshot.data!.docs[index]['senderId'] !=
                        snapshot.data!.docs[index + 1]['senderId']) {
                      // print('vod');
                      sendId = 3;
                    }
                  }
                  var cond = index - 1 < 0;
                  if (!cond) {
                    if (snapshot.data!.docs[index]['senderId'] !=
                        snapshot.data!.docs[index - 1]['senderId']) {
                      sendId = 1;
                    }
                  }
                }
                return ChatBubble(
                    isMe: globalProviderState.getID ==
                        snapshot.data!.docs[index]['senderId'],
                    messageType: snapshot.data!.docs[index]['messageType'],
                    styleId: sendId,
                    message: snapshot.data!.docs[index]['message'],
                    profileImg: widget.profileUrl);
              }),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

Issue is how can i scroll to end when list load the data? Because it's working fine when i use this function onTap but if i use it in initState it's showing error because till data in list was not loaded. Is it any way when List loaded in Stream then it will automatically scroll down to end ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timer on initiate method like

```
Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), (Timer timer) {
   if (_controller.hasClients) {
     _scrollDown();
     timer.cancel();
   }
});
```